# How many different teams can be created between two groups?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If a company has 8 painters and 12 electricians. How many different teams can be created with 1 painter and 1 electrician?

I know that the number of ways a team can be made is:

> $ {8 \choose 1} * {12 \choose 1} $

Because for each of the eight painters there can be one of the twelve painters, but how many different possibilities of teams are there? I know there will be 8 teams, and that four electricians will sit out, but I don't know how to get the number of possible teams.

Comment: How large is a team? If there are two members to a team, your answer is already OK.

Comment: No, I don't think the above works. The above is just showing how many options for one single team there are. I need to know how many possible teams can exist.

Comment: But, how large is a team??

Comment: Two members - one painter and one electrician.

Comment: Then there are 8 times 12 = 96 teams

Comment: That number feels too small though. If I have 8 teams, each one will be paired with an electrician, but don't I need to consider who is paired with who? Like a permutation?

Comment: That number is too small. Consider if we have $3$ painters and $3$ electricians. We match $(p_{1}, e_{1})$. Now there are two possibilities matching $p_{2}, p_{3}$ with $e_{2}, e_{3}$. So there are $6$ total possibilities (notice $6 = 3!$ here). Consider similar enumerative logic with $4$ of each. So we match $(p_{1}, e_{1})$ and have $p_{2}, p_{3}, p_{4}$ to match with $e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{4}$. We know that there are $6$ ways of handling the subproblem. There are $4$ such matchings of $p_{1}$, giving us $4 * 3! = 4!$ ways for $n = 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the bijection counting rule. We are mapping: Painters to Electricians using a one-to-one relation.

So how many injective functions $f: P \to E$ are there? The answer is $12!/4!$. For $p_{1} \in P$, $f(p_{1})$ has $12$ options. For $p_{2}$, $f(p_{2})$ has $11$ options. We keep proceeding in this manner.

Comment: Why is it not 12!/8!? The answer you gave is a number of about 19.9 million, which seems a bit large

Comment: We are permuting $8$ of the $12$ elements, so we have $P(12, 8) = 12!/(12-8)!$. You can double check the formula here, for example: http://www.mathwords.com/p/permutation_formula.htm

Combinatorial results often are quite large. So don't be intimidated by that. Does the logic make sense, though?

Comment: The logic does make sense. I think we (there are about 5 of us arguing over this) will discuss it with the professor but I do believe that this is a permutation.

Comment: Sounds good! Let us know what the outcome is. :-)

Comment: Got our quiz back today. We had a really similar question on the quiz, and this was the right answer. I'm so glad I came here first, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)